# conditional update on same column

Tags: sql, oracle

Pl find code below

```
SQL> desc aaa
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(1)

SQL> select * from aaa;

E
-
2
2
2
5
5
5
5

7 rows selected.
```

I need to update 2 with 5 and 5 with 2 with a single sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update aaa set ename = translate(ename, '25', '52')
```

or

```
update aaa set ename = decode(ename, '5', '2', '2', '5', ename)
```

Comment: The first will set `ename` to NULL if it was neither '2' or '5'. A `WHERE` clause should be added.

Comment: it won't, at least in my 9i. check this: `select translate('7', '25', '52')  from dual`.

Comment: here's what the manual says: `translate('char', 'from_string', 'to_string')`: TRANSLATE returns `char` with all occurrences of each character in `from_string` replaced by its corresponding character in `to_string`. Characters in `char` that are not in `from_string` are not replaced.

Answer (score 6):

```
update
  aaa
set
  ENAME = case when ENAME = '2' then '5' else '2' end
where
  ENAME in ('2', '5')
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the information provided and requirement:

In t-sql you can do this like

```
update aaa set Ename = case when Ename = '2' then '5' else '2' end
```

Change case statement with oracle equivalent

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  aaa
SET E = 7 - E
WHERE E IN (5,2)
```

Comment: No it wouldn't.  Also what would happen to a row where E = 4?

Comment: `set E = to_char(7 - to_number(E))`